# Linked lists are not modified through function (C programming)

Tags: c, linked-list

I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct node {
    int value;
    struct node* next;
};

typedef struct node Sequence;


Sequence* init() {

    Sequence* s = NULL;
    return s;
}

void insertFirstElement(Sequence* s, int e) {

    if (s == NULL) {

        s = (Sequence*)malloc(sizeof(Sequence));
        s->value = e;
        s->next = NULL;
        return;
    }
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    Sequence* s = NULL;
    s = (Sequence*)malloc(sizeof(Sequence));
    s->value = 5;
    s->next = NULL;

    if (s == NULL) {

        printf("Doesn't work!\n");
    }
    else {

        printf("It works!\n");
    }

    Sequence* s2 = init();
    insertFirstElement(s2, 5);

    if (s2 == NULL) {

        printf("Doesn't work!\n");
    }
    else {

        printf("It works!\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And program print this:

```
It works!
Doesn't work!
```

So I doesn't understand why I can't modify my linked list through 'insertFirstElement' function. Why 'Sequence' it is not updated after function call? Why it remains 'NULL'? Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: because in `insertFirstElement` your `s` is modified locally and that's it, the assignment doesn't get passed back. You have a memory leak (you are malloc'ing and then never freeing it)

Comment: The function modifies a *copy* of the variable, which is forgotten at function exit.

Comment: Hands up all those who knew what the problem was from the title:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass pointer by value in `insertFirstElement` function. After returning from function, the address of pointer remains unchanged. You need to pass pointer to pointer such that,

```
void insertFirstElement(Sequence** s, int e) {

    if (*s == NULL) {

        *s = (Sequence*)malloc(sizeof(Sequence));
        (*s)->value = e;
        (*s)->next = NULL;
        return;
    }
}
```

Accordingly, calling function, `insertFirstElement(s2, 5);` is modified as 
 `insertFirstElement(&s2, 5);`

Comment: I thought that to use dynamically initialization modify directly the argument, which moreover is a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

In the function **void insertFirstElement(Sequence* s, int e)**

since the linkedlist will get modified therefore use call by reference (you are using call by value method).

try void insertFirstElement(Sequence** s, int e)

Answer (score -1):

on the line

```
s = (Sequence*)malloc(sizeof(Sequence));
```

you replace the sequence you were given with a new sequence. You take in an address pointing at a sequence, but then replace that address with a new address pointing at a new sequence. You'd need to change the sequence s was pointing at without changing where s is pointing to modify the sequence in a way that will be reflected outside the function.